# onclick affecting child elements

Tags: javascript, parent-child, scrollto

I have a page with a list of thumbnails wrapped in a containing div. When the containing div is clicked the user scrolls to the next row of thumbnails.

However each thumbnail div is also a link and when clicked the scroll event is still occurring.

Is there a way to stop the javascript affecting these child thumbnail elements?

heres the problem:
http://codepen.io/anon/pen/Apelg/

N.B. The links are target _blank but you'll notice returning to the page that you've scrolled to the next div and this is what i'm trying to avoid.

Answer (score 0):

You have to catch the click on the thumbnail and use `e.stopPropagation` to prevent the bubbling to the div

```
$('.thumbnail').click(function(e){
    e.stopPropagation();
});

// OR

<img src="thumbnail.jpg" onclick="event.stopPropagation()" />
```

Comment: `stopPropagation` is actually native JavaScript I believe; not just jQuery

Comment: I actually dont know. Lets research that^^

Comment: Thanks for this. However the first click on the page still scrolls when clicking on a thumbnail. All clicks after that are ok though. See here: [link](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/yvJqE/)